# Pushing a Slack Notification into SQL Database

Tags: sql, slack

I have a situation where I have an application which generates a slack notification, what I am trying to do is to take that slack notification and push that notification to SQL, convert the notification, and write the data to a table in SQL.

Comment: Where's the question? What specific problem are you facing? What have you tried? Why didn't that work? What error messages did you get?

Comment: There is no error message I do not know how to integrate slack into SQL all my searches have been sending SQL alerts into slack, I am trying to do the reverse, this is all new to me.

Comment: Met it when browsing slack api docs https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api#subscriptions . My guess this is how you're getting events you want in slack and then you can process it at will. Never worked with slack personally.